# Source tree unable to index added files to eclipse android project

Tags: android, eclipse, atlassian-sourcetree

The problem is when I add .png file into drawable folder, SourceTree cannot see new file in project...

Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is just simply select "Team-> Add to Index" and now I can see the new file in SourceTree window ready for commit

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using git, check if your `.gitignore` is configured to ignore `.png` or everything under a directory, such as `drawable`.